# The Sonarqube Java analyser throws NullPointerException during code analysis, when using lambdas without arguments

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Sonarqube (version 5.1.1 with Java-Plugin version 3.3 and Maven-Sonar-Plugin version 2.6) crashes with a NPE during code analysis.

This seems to happen, when you use Lambdas without arguments.

Here's a code example for that case:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Foobar {

  public Object foobar() {
    return Arrays
    .asList("1", "2", "3")
    .stream()
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> "FOOBAR");
  }

}
```

Does the Java-Plugin not support those expressions yet?

Any ideas how to fix that without excluding all such classes?

**Edit - Here's the stacktrace:**

```
Unable to analyze .class file Foobar
    at     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to analyze .class file Foobar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyze .class file Foobar
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.notifyBytecodeVisitors(BytecodeScanner.java:82)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.scanClasses(BytecodeScanner.java:60)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.scan(BytecodeScanner.java:51)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanBytecode(JavaSquid.java:146)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:126)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.java.signature.ParameterSignaturePrinter.print(ParameterSignaturePrinter.java:28)
    at org.sonar.java.signature.MethodSignaturePrinter.print(MethodSignaturePrinter.java:32)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.BytecodeVisitor.getMethodLineNumber(BytecodeVisitor.java:69)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck.visitMethod(RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck.java:57)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethod(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:74)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.callVisitMethodAndFieldAndEdge(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:55)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeVisitorNotifier.notifyVisitors(BytecodeVisitorNotifier.java:48)
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.notifyBytecodeVisitors(BytecodeScanner.java:80)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the stacktrace,

Comment: I can't reproduce it with your snippet compiled with java 8 oracle, which compiler did you use to compile your class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@benzonico 
Thanks for that hint. We're using an eclipse compiler, which happened to be not the latest version and caused the problems.

For others with similar problems:
You need to use the following combination in your maven-poms:

```
org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-jdt:0.23.0
org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.11.0.v20150520-2033
```